# OCR software for Windows, with support for non-English language

Tags: windows-7, windows, ocr

Precisely, I would like to find an OCR software which can convert PDF files and images to text.

Also, it should support "Hungarian" language. I tried looking around, searching for such a software, but I couldn't find a list, a comparison, a recommendation... anything.

(**No problem** if it's **not** free.)

Comment: I will enlighten you one of my favorite things about Wikipedia: comparisons. See: [Comparison of optical character recognition software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_optical_character_recognition_software)

Comment: What Wikipedia should and will tell: Specifications, facts. What I need is recommendations, solution for the problem. Not a marketing text, or just a software name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to try FineReader, it does support Hungarian (full list of languages it supports is [here](http://finereader.abbyy.com/recognition_languages/)), and it worked perfectly with both Russian and English languages in my experience.

Comment: Thanks, it works really great. Sorry for the late accept.